# Laravel Response::make, but file automatically start to download

Tags: laravel

On my project, I need to show the preview of the pdf file, I'm using this code below in order to open the pdf preview. When I ran the code, the file that should've been previewed, but it's starting to download instead. Is there anything wrong with my code? It should've been `Response::download` to download the file right?

```
public function showFile(Request $request)
{
$partisipan = Partisipan::where('id', $request->partisipan_id)->first();
$filePath = $partisipan[$request->filename];

return Response::make( file_get_contents(public_path($filePath)), 200, [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
   'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="filename.pdf"',
]);
}
```

**Edited**

Just for information, my file path is stored on db using `Storage::url`. I've been accessed the file using `public_path` for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using file() method instead:

```
return response()->file( public_path($filePath),[
   'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
   'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="filename.pdf"',
]);
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253228/discussion-on-answer-by-khang-tran-laravel-responsemake-but-file-automaticall); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.